# Dropping range of columns from DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, multiple-columns

I have a `dataframe` whose columns I want to drop can be listed by using `df._get_numeric_data()`.

If I write

```
for df.column in df._get_numeric_data(): 
    print(df.column)
```

I will get a list of all the columns in type string I want to drop.

```
Unnamed: 2
Unnamed: 4
Unnamed: 6
Unnamed: 8
Unnamed: 10
Unnamed: 12
Unnamed: 13
Unnamed: 15
Unnamed: 19
Unnamed: 21
Unnamed: 22
Unnamed: 24
Unnamed: 26
Unnamed: 28
Week Ending
Unnamed: 31
Unnamed: 34
Unnamed: 35
Unnamed: 37
Unnamed: 42
Unnamed: 47
```

I'm trying to figure out how to drop all those columns in one go. I tried

```
for df.column in df._get_numeric_data():
    df.drop(df.column)
```

But get an error:

> KeyError: "['Unnamed: 2'] not found in axis"

I tried a few other things, and think I'm not far off, but something about the `df.drop(df.column)` isn't correct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `axis=1`, `drop` default is to drop the `index`

```
for df.column in df._get_numeric_data():
    df.drop(df.column,axis=1)
```

Also no need for loop

```
df=df.drop(df._get_numeric_data().column,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much